# Apache Shiro Session Leak on Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, shiro

I have implemented Apache Shiro and once in a while, we get a session leak incidence. It's strange because a user logs in, only to see a message that they're logged in as somebody else. It's a bit rare but it happens. What could be causing this??

Comment: I'm guessing you are spawning threads from somewhere in your request? Otherwise, see: https://shiro.apache.org/security-reports.html

Comment: Yea seen that @brian-demers thanks.